# Theme menu in Admin Panel

Tags: menus, wp-admin, admin-menu

I am new in WordPress Development. How can I get `Menus` in Admin Panel like below ?

[image]

I am trying to develop a theme. But I couldn't display that.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register custom menus in your theme - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu

You first need to register your menu in functions.php like so:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu' );
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu', 'theme-slug' ) );
}
```

Then, where you want your menu to appear - usually header.php - you call the function:

```
wp_nav_menu()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to [this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) for more information.

Basically, for Menus to show up, you need to use the WordPress function `register_nav_menu()` to register that your theme supports at least 1 menu. Each registered menu corresponds to a checkbox under the *Display location* (which is under the **Menu Settings** header) section at the bottom of the Menu page.

[image: Display location menus]